# How to force landscape print in PDF file

Tags: asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation

Pertains to a C#.net website... I would like to generate a pdf file server side, have it open on the client, and automatically print with landscape orientation. Is this possible? Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What for a tool/library do you use to create pdf?

Comment: I foresee you will have problems with the "automatically" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can orient a PDF into landscape, but you cannot set a printer to automatically print in landscape mode. This is a setting that you do not have access to from the browser.